# Check if a record exists in an array using PDO and Mysql

Tags: php, arrays, pdo, array-key-exists

I'm trying to get a record in my mysql whether a record exists or not in an array. I've searched online about using array_key_exists function and unfortunately it always gives me "Match not found" even though the record exists in the array.

**This is my output.**

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [GUESTCHECK] => 10017 [0] => 10017 ) [1] => Array ( [GUESTCHECK] => 10024 [0] => 10024 ) [2] => Array ( [GUESTCHECK] => 10066 [0] => 10066 ) [3] => Array ( [GUESTCHECK] => 10084 [0] => 10084 ) [4] => Array ( [GUESTCHECK] => 10150 [0] => 10150 ) [5] => Array ( [GUESTCHECK] => 10154 [0] => 10154 ) [6] => Array ( [GUESTCHECK] => 10223 [0] => 10223 ) [7] => Array ( [GUESTCHECK] => 10224 [0] => 10224 ) [8] => Array ( [GUESTCHECK] => 10225 [0] => 10225 ) [9] => Array ( [GUESTCHECK] => 10261 [0] => 10261 ) [10] => Array ( [GUESTCHECK] => 10284 [0] => 10284 ) [11] => Array ( [GUESTCHECK] => 10298 [0] => 10298 ) [12] => Array ( [GUESTCHECK] => 20012 [0] => 20012 ) [13] => Array ( [GUESTCHECK] => 20014 [0] => 20014 ) [14] => Array ( [GUESTCHECK] => 20054 [0] => 20054 ) [15] => Array ( [GUESTCHECK] => 20056 [0] => 20056 ) [16] => Array ( [GUESTCHECK] => 20061 [0] => 20061 ) [17] => Array ( [GUESTCHECK] => 20131 [0] => 20131 ) [18] => Array ( [GUESTCHECK] => 20160 [0] => 20160 ) [19] => Array ( [GUESTCHECK] => 20163 [0] => 20163 ) [20] => Array ( [GUESTCHECK] => 20183 [0] => 20183 ) ) )
```

Help me by telling what's wrong with my code?

```
  $gchecksummary = "SELECT DISTINCT GUESTCHECK FROM `items` 
where CODE = 771012 and DATE = '1/1/2018' or CODE = 771013 
and DATE = '1/1/2018' or CODE = 782012 
and DATE = '1/1/2018' or CODE = 774012 
and DATE = '1/1/2018' or CODE = 775203 
and DATE = '1/1/2018' or CODE = 775202 and DATE = '1/1/2018'";
$execgchecksummary  = $conn->prepare($gchecksummary);
$execgchecksummary->execute();


while($fetchgchecksummary = $execgchecksummary->fetchAll()){

$results[] = $fetchgchecksummary;

} 


 print_r($results);
 echo "<br />";

 if (array_key_exists("10017", $results))
  {
  echo "Match found";
  }
else
  {
  echo "Match not found";
  }
```

Comment: you have to give key name not value....

Comment: @RohitChauhan hmm..  I want to get the value though... I've tried in_array as well and it still didn't match.. in_array("10017", $results)

Comment: is value 10017 is string ???

Comment: if not then try without quotes

Comment: I've tried it without quotes, its still did not match

Comment: print array and put output in question

Comment: ... Is there a reason why you don't want to put the criteria in the query and check if any rows are returned?

Comment: @RohitChauhan i've added the output

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams i'm sorry but I can't seem to understand your question, may I know which criteria in the query you are talking about? all I did was get the values that came out from my query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is in Your code logic and sql query.

Why to take array of unnecessary rows and do lookup in it?

Also You're repeating `DATE` condition with same value multiple times

You can just define condition for `GUESTCHECK` inside Your query, then  check result count and do `fetchAll` (if there's a need on data).

Example with rows data:

```
  $query = "
    SELECT * 
    FROM `items` 
    WHERE 
     GUESTCHECK = 10017 
      AND
     CODE IN (771012, 782012, 774012, 775203, 775202) 
      AND
     DATE = '1/1/2018'
  ";

  $statement = $conn->prepare($query);
  $statement->execute();

  if ($statement->rowCount() > 0)
  {
    echo "Match found";

    $items = $statement->fetchAll();
    var_dump($items);
  }
  else
  {
    echo "Match not found";
  }
```

Example without getting rows from db:

```
  $query = "
    SELECT 1
    FROM `items` 
    WHERE 
     GUESTCHECK = 10017 
      AND
     CODE IN (771012, 782012, 774012, 775203, 775202) 
      AND
     DATE = '1/1/2018'
    LIMIT 1
  ";

  $statement = $conn->prepare($query);
  $statement->execute();

  if ($statement->rowCount() > 0)
  {
    echo "Match found";
  }
  else
  {
    echo "Match not found";
  }
```

p.s. make sure You've added index to `GUESTCHECK` and `CODE` fields to help DB engine to search for data effectively.